# Is there a way to call multiple get and post requests in a flask appfrom an IOS app

Tags: python, ios, mysql, swift, flask

So I have an app that needs to read and write to multiple tables of a mysql database from different views within itself. I currently can preform one get and post request with the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
import mysql.connector

#opens database connectionto "events" database
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="correct horse battery staple", database = "events")
    print("Connection OK")

except e:
    print("Connection failed: ", e)
#prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        event_id = request.form['a']
        poi = request.form['b']
        address = request.form['c']
        start_time = request.form['d']
        end_time = request.form['e']

        sql = "INSERT INTO events (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time)


        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
           mycursor.execute(sql, val)
           # Commit your changes in the database
           mydb.commit()
           mydb.close()
        except e:
           # Rollback in case there is any error
           print("Error: ", e)
           mydb.rollback()

        return make_response("Success!", 200)

    elif flask.request.method == 'GET':


           return make_response("Success!", 200)

print("DB is closed")
```

Say I need to also create and access a users table from the same data base but in a different view, how could I do this by modifying this code. Or is there anyway at all to achieve these results using a flask server and ios. Is it possible to achieve this with multiple @app.route pointing to diffent pages of a website like /users

Comment: As a rule try not to paste your password details, use `passwd="xxxx"` instead. Even if it's only for your local db.

Answer (score 0):

The `route()` decorator is binding a function to a URL

You can also pass params through the URL

```
@app.route('/users/<int:user_id>')
def show_user(user_id):
    ....
```

---

You have already create one route with :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    ....
```

If you want an other route to fetch and update users, you can add an other function like this

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users():
    ....
```